# PL/SQL comma delimited list; remove dups and put in array

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a comma delimited list as a string in a PL/SQL procedure. I need to

1. Remove duplicates
2. Put the list in an array.

I have found multiple ways to do either, just not both.
Any help?

Comment: If you know how to do each part,  why is it a problem for you to combine them together?

Comment: Atleast give a try and post what you tried.

Comment: The issue is the methods for removing duplicates seems a bit unreliable. In running the examples some don't work at all, give the wrong set or leave commas. (which I guess i could eliminate.) Most of them use an array of one form or another to go from list to array, but those array types are not conducive to the duplicate removal techniques. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a well-known SQL trick for turning comma-separated lists into rows.  Just use that trick, add a `DISTINCT` keyword, and `BULK COLLECT` the results into your array (I assume you mean collection).

```
DECLARE
  p_test_string   VARCHAR2 (4000) := 'A,B,C,B,B,D';

  TYPE string_array_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (4000);

  l_array         string_array_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR (p_test_string,
                        '[^,]+',
                        1,
                        LEVEL)
  BULK   COLLECT INTO l_array
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (p_test_string,
                            '[^,]+',
                            1,
                            LEVEL)
               IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY 1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('l_array.count = ' || l_array.COUNT);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('l_array(2) = ' || l_array (2));
END;
```

Output:

```
l_array.count = 4
l_array(2) = B
```

Comment: Thanks much! Worked! Not to grouse (ok a little) some one, who knows more than me, should create a good strings package with things like duplicate delete and such.

Comment: If you want to make this into a library, for widespread use, you should implement MT0's solution (which I'll upvote).  He's right that a pure PL/SQL approach will be much faster (probably on the order of 20-30 _times_ faster).  If you are only calling this a few times, I'd favor the approach I posted for its simplicity.  If you are calling this a million times, or are making it into a library, I'd favor MT0's solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple methods to [split a delimited string](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings). One of which is to use a simple PL/SQL function:

```
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN STRING_LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       STRING_LIST := STRING_LIST();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

This is a pure PL/SQL function using simple string functions (rather than using more expensive regular expressions and context switches into an SQL scope).

There is also a very simple, built-in, function [`SET( collection_value )`](http://psoug.org/reference/collect_func.html) for removing duplicates from a collection:

```
SET( STRING_LIST( 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B' ) )
```

Will give the collection:

```
STRING_LIST( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
```

So, if you want to split a delimited string and de-duplicate it then you can just do:

```
SET( split_String( 'A,B,C,A,B,D,C,E' ) )
```

Which will give you:

```
STRING_LIST( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' )
```