# Oracle SQL - How to Cut out characters from a string with SUBSTR?

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I have values like `"ABC1234", "ABC", "DEF456", "GHI"` etc. in a specific column which I need.

Now I need to split this string but only if the character (e.g. "ABC") are followed by digits.

So if the value is `"ABC1234"` then I need to cut out ABC and 1234 seperated. But if there is only "ABC" as a value, I just need the "ABC". I can't find any solution with `SUBSTR`. Do you have any idea?

Note: The length of the characters can differ from 1 to 10 and also the length from the digits (sometimes there isn't any like I showed you).

Comment: What about if you have AB12CD34 ?

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: Please edit the original post to show an example of actual data before and after processing.  Do you have the power to fix the database design or are you stuck with this violation of 1st normal form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if the value is "ABC1234" then I need to cut out ABC and 1234
>   seperated. But if there is only "ABC" as a value, I just need the
>   "ABC".

Amidst of other solutions, I propose one solution as shown below:

***Logic***:

> 1) Replace all the digits to `1`. Check the position of the `digit` occurring in the `string`. If
>   there is no digit in the string then use the `String`.
>
> 2) Extract the alphabets from `1st` position to the position where
>   digit starts.
>
> 3) Extract the digit from the position it starts till end. If digit doesnot exists the set it `NULL`

```
  --Dataset Preparation
    with test (col) as
      (select 'ABC1234' from dual union all
       select 'ABC'     from dual union all
       select 'dEfH456'  from dual union all
       select '123GHI'  from dual union all
       select '456'     from dual
      )
     --Query
    select col Original_Column, 
           CASE 
              WHEN (instr(regexp_replace(col,'[0-9]','1'),'1',1)) = 0
           then col
           else
           substr( col,1,instr(regexp_replace(col,'[0-9]','1'),'1',1)-1) 
           end Col_Alp,

           CASE 
              WHEN (instr(regexp_replace(col,'[0-9]','1'),'1',1)) = 0
            then NULL
            Else
            substr( col,instr(regexp_replace(col,'[0-9]','1'),'1',1)) 
            END col_digit    
   from test
   where regexp_like(col, '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$');
```

Result:

```
SQL> /
Original_Column Col_Alp col_digit
----------      -----   -----
ABC1234      ABC       1234
ABC          ABC       NULL
dEfH456      dEfH      456
123GHI       NULL       123GHI
456          NULL       456
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this do?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '"ABC1234", "ABC", "dEf456", "123GHI", "456"' from dual),
  3  inter as
  4    (select trim(regexp_substr(replace(col, '"', ''), '[^,]+', 1, level)) token
  5     from test
  6     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
  7    )
  8  select regexp_substr(token, '^[a-zA-Z]+') letters,
  9         regexp_substr(token, '[0-9]+$') digits
 10  from inter
 11  where regexp_like(token, '^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+$');

LETTERS    DIGITS
---------- ----------
ABC        1234
dEf        456

SQL>
```

Comment: I have more than 1.000 values in that column. They are also added dozens daily. I can't write a `SELECT` for each of them.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that all those columns are in a same column. I edited my answer; have a look, please, @fnr.

Answer (score 1):

Using `SUBSTR` (and `INSTR` and `TRANSLATE`):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f8c8/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'ABC1234'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC123D'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC '        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEFG456'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JKLMNOPQRS9' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value,
       SUBSTR( value, 1, first_digit - 1 ) AS prefix,
       TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( value, first_digit ) ) AS suffix
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(
           TRANSLATE( value, '-1234567890', ' ----------' ),
           '-',
           1
         ) AS first_digit
  FROM   data
)
WHERE  SUBSTR( value, first_digit ) IS NOT NULL
AND    TRANSLATE( SUBSTR( value, first_digit ), '-1234567890', ' ' ) IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f8c8/2/0)**:

```
|       VALUE |     PREFIX | SUFFIX |
|-------------|------------|--------|
|     ABC1234 |        ABC |   1234 |
|     DEFG456 |       DEFG |    456 |
| JKLMNOPQRS9 | JKLMNOPQRS |      9 |
```

Comment: This does not work. How I've said `ABC123` is not a column, it's a value from over 1.000 different values. Also it can be `ABCDEFG1234567` so your SUBSTR with "1, 3" would not work

Comment: @fnr Updated for different length values. Just use any of the [many, many ways to split a delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380811/1509264) so that the values are in a column. (And then update your data structures so that they are sensibly stored in a column rather than trying to use delimited strings.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this below query for scenarios mentioned , I didn't split if characters followed by numbers:

```
with test (col) as
  (select 'ABC1234' from dual union all
   select 'ABC'     from dual union all
   select 'dEfH456'  from dual union all
   select '123GHI'  from dual union all
   select '456'     from dual
  )

  select col,reverse(trim(regexp_replace(reverse(col),'^[0-9]+',' '))) string ,trim(regexp_replace(col,'^[a-zA-Z]+',' ')) numbers from test
```

if like to move that characters&string to any place my case statement

```
with test (col) as
  (select 'ABC1234' from dual union all
   select 'ABC'     from dual union all
   select 'dEfH456'  from dual union all
   select '123GHI'  from dual union all
   select '456'     from dual
  )

  select v.col,case when v.string=v.numbers THEN NULL ELSE string end string , v.numbers
  from (select col,reverse(trim(regexp_replace(reverse(col),'^[0-9]+',' '))) string ,trim(regexp_replace(col,'^[a-zA-Z]+',' ')) numbers from test) v
```